# Can someone help me with controling Snake Game in Java Processing

Tags: java, keyboard, processing

I am doing a basic Snake Game in Java Processing. It is supposed to turn clockwise whne the user presses L or D, and when the user presses the A or J key the snake should turn counter-clockwise. The keys should not directly control the snake's direction. They should control how the snake turns.

DEMO
[Look at DEMO Question 2](http://file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/Telegram%20Desktop/Assignment%205%20Demos.html)

QUESTION
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQJqq.png)

My Code

```
 final int ROWS=20, COLS=15; //The number of rows and columns of squares
 final int SQ_SIZE=40;       //The size of each square in pixels
 final int[] X_DIRECTIONS = {0, -1, 0, 1}; //X change for down, left, up, right
 final int[] Y_DIRECTIONS = {1, 0, -1, 0}; //Y change for down, left, up, right

 int startingLength = 5, currentLength = 0, snakeSpeed = 30, currentDirection = 0;
 int [] x = new int[ROWS*COLS];
 int [] y = new int[ROWS*COLS];

 void setup(){
   background(#ff9900);
   size(600,800); //MUST be COLS*SQ_SIZE, ROWS*SQ_SIZE
   resetSnake();
 }

 void draw(){
   if(frameCount % snakeSpeed == 0){
       background(#ff9900);  
       drawCircles(x, y, currentLength, #32CD32);
       moveSnake(X_DIRECTIONS[currentDirection],  Y_DIRECTIONS[currentDirection]);
       //moveSnake(X_DIRECTIONS[currentDirection], 0);
   }  
 }

 void resetSnake(){
   currentLength = startingLength;
   fillArray(y, currentLength, ROWS/2, -1);
   fillArray(x, currentLength, COLS/2, 0);
   drawCircles(x, y, currentLength, #32CD32);
 }

 void moveSnake(int addX, int addY){
   if(addX != 0){
     fillArray(x, currentLength, x[0] + addX, addX);
   } 
   fillArray(y, currentLength, y[0] + addY, -addY);
 }

 void keyPressed(){
   int newDir = keyCode == DOWN ? 0:(keyCode == UP ? 2:(keyCode == RIGHT ? 3:(keyCode == LEFT ? 1:-1)));
   if(newDir != -1) currentDirection = newDir;  
 }



 void drawCircles(int[]x, int[]y, int n, int colour){
   //Draw circles here
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
      fill(colour);
      circle(x[i]*SQ_SIZE, y[i]*SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE);
    }
 }

 void fillArray(int[] a, int n, int start, int delta){
   int index = 0;
   if(delta > 0){
     for(int i = start; i < start + n; i+=delta){
       a[index++] = i;
     }
   }else if(delta < 0){
      for(int i = start; i > start-n; i+=delta){
      a[index++] = i;
      }
   }else{
     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
       a[index++] = start;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: have a look above there is a question

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the directions in an array, you can "rotate" through them like this:

```
void keyPressed(){
    if (keyCode == 76 //the code for 'l'
     || keyCode == 68) { //the code for 'd'
        currentDirection++;
        if(currentDirection > 3) { //make sure currentDirection is not bigger than the array length
            currentDirection = 0;
        }
    }

    if (keyCode == 65 //the code for 'a'
     || keyCode == 74) { //the code for 'j'
        currentDirection--;
        if (currentDirection < 0) { //make sure currentDirection is not smaller than 0
            currentDirection = 3;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: please help me I have to finish it today it is not rotating properly

Comment: file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/Telegram%20Desktop/Assignment%205%20Demos.html

Have a look at Question 2, it shows how it is supposed to work!

Comment: First of all, please excuse my late answer. Second of all, this site isn't meant to be used for "please do my assignment" questions. Also, the "link" you posted only works for you (notice that it is a local file path). You would have had to upload the file somewhere